# JQM - data-rel='back' doesn't save drop down choice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a page with a couple of drop downs, that get dynamic values in pagebeforeshow.

I open page1 from other links:

```
page1.html?flag=open&class=CR&category=&prod=&t=t
```

page1 init selected values come from the link in a query string.

User chooses some options from these drop downs.
After user chooses the option he can click on a link to another page. Page2.html

In page2.html I want to give the option of going back to page1.html

```
 <a  class='ui-btn-left' data-icon='back' data-rel="back" data-theme="a"  data-iconpos="notext">back</a>
```

However when I click on it, all user choices are gone. It shows init choice from the query string. Shouldn't it show user choices?

How to fix these issue? I know I can save choices with sessionStorage and pull it using other options besides data-rel="back". I want it to work with the data-rel="back".

Comment: Is page1.html is initial page? If not, one of possible solutions is to cache that page, since external pages are removed from DOM when you navigate away.

Comment: Doesn't it make it slower if I cache it?

Comment: when a page is cached, jqm doesn't reload it.

Comment: So it's better than using sessionStorage? I load page with data from db, then store values in sessionStotage, then load them when user goes back to page.

Comment: Web site is for mobile devices also. So I need the fastest way.